# Apple Development: Release iOS 7 app

Tags: ios, app-store, updates

I will soon be uploading a new app to the App store. I have a question concerning the build version of the app. Does Apple still allow us to upload an app that has been build for iOS 7, since I know Apple is kind of forceful about staying up-to-date. I can't find anything about it while googling.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean _deployment target_ or _Base SDK_? There's no problem with an iOS 7 deployment target (you can go as low as you like…). But if you linking against the Base SDK of iOS 7, then the question is: why?

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to mention: I mean as in deployment target. My Base SDK is 8.4 Thank you

Comment: yes its good the application is supporting previous version of iOS. And it should also capable of running on latest OS version

Comment: @DarkDust if you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *deployment target* is the lowest iOS version your app is supporting and Apple doesn't limit that (AFAIK). So if you want to (and are able to), you can still submit an app that runs on iOS 5, for example (iOS 5.1.1 is the newest iOS version for first-generation iPads).

Apple does specify the lowest acceptable *Base SDK* (the libraries you're linking against) when submitting, though (they change this every few months/years and announce this to developers via e-mail). If you're using the latest non-beta Xcode, you're always fine. Submissions from Xcode beta version are never accepted.